# To remove array string item from config file

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

How to remove a string array item from the config file?

```
<configuration>
  <applicationSettings>
    <Sample.Service.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="SampleAttribute" serializeAs="Xml">
        <value>
          <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <string>firstemail@domain.com</string>
            <string>secondemail@domain.com</string>
          </ArrayOfString>
        </value>
```

I am able to access the first item (firstemail@domain.com) from the config file and can replace the value by the following code.
But my question is how to remove the second item(secondemail@domain.com) from the config file through following similar code.

```
    {
"configuration/applicationSettings/Sample.Service.Properties.Settings/setting[@name='SampleAttribute']/value/ArrayOfString/string[0]":"$(SampleAttribute)"
}
```

Comment: Can you tell what task do you use to apply this transformation?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej, I am using `Config Transform` task.

Answer (score 0):

> To remove array string item from config file

I am afraid we could not use the File Transform (not sure whether the `Config Transform` you said is `file Transform` or `Config Transformation`) to remove the array string item.

To resolve this issue, you could use the task [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) to replace the first item and remove the second item:

The format of variable in config file is `#{EmailOne}#` & `#{EmailTwo}#`.

My test config file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <applicationSettings>
    <Sample.Service.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="SampleAttribute" serializeAs="Xml">
        <value>
          <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <string>#{EmailOne}#</string>
            #{EmailTwo}#
          </ArrayOfString>
        </value>
      </setting>
    </Sample.Service.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then we just need to define the variable EmailOne and EmailTwo in the Variables with replace value and **empty** value:

[image]

The test result:

[image]

**Inline Powershell Scripts:**

```
$appConfigFile = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\xxx\xxx\web.config" #change the path to your config file.

$appConfig = New-Object XML
$appConfig.Load($appConfigFile)
foreach($BuildNumber in $appConfig.configuration.applicationSettings."Sample.Service.Properties.Settings".setting.value.ArrayOfString)
{

$BuildNumber.RemoveChild($BuildNumber.FirstChild.NextSibling)


}
$appConfig.Save($appConfigFile)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. In the above answer, we need to add `#` in the config file. Is there any way without editing the config file, can we achieve this.

Comment: @Developer, The answer should be yes, we could use powershell scripts to remove it by scripts. But this requires us to be proficient in powershell scripts. For powershell, I only know a little, I am afraid I can't provide you with a complete code. Use above task, it will be very easy to achieve.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am updating the question tag to include `Powershell` tag.

Comment: @Developer, You are always welcome. Hope that some experts in powershell can provide a perfect solution (although this is a bit difficult). In addition, I will try to write it. I will let you know the results. Have a nice day.

Comment: @Developer, I have created a powershell scripts to resolve this issue, and I test it works fine on my side.

Comment: Can we use the same shell script as you mentioned. I am seeing you have used `$BuildNumber` in the foreach loop. Can you explain how to use this. Thanks

Comment: @Developer, Why you use the shell script? I do not mentioned it in my answer, what I said is powershell not the shell. The $BuildNumber is a custom variable, it can be any other string, like teststring.

Comment: What should be the value we need to provide for this variable.

Comment: @Developer, No, you do not need provide any for this variable, this is just a custom temporary variable used to store the obtained node value. You could add a inline powershell task to copy my scripts, the **only thing to modify** is the path `appConfigFile`, since I do not know your file directory agency.